# Shares traded and Volume Confusion

Tags: stocks, transaction

I don't understand something about an insider transaction report.

According to [this report](http://openinsider.com/search?q=FARM) an insider sold 40000 shares on 2003/12/24.  But when I look at [publicly available](http://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=203008&startdate=Dec+23%2C+2003&enddate=Dec+23%2C+2003) [volume data](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=FARM&a=11&b=23&c=2003&d=11&e=23&f=2003&g=d) for that date, the volume is only 1000.

How is that possible?  Shouldn't the volume be at least 40000 shares?

Comment: Are you sure the volume is not in thousands/millions?

Comment: Yes I am very sure. I thought am I missing sth?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://openinsider.com/search?q=FARM ---SEE THE TRANSACTIONS BELOW ON DATE 12/24/2003  AND ALSO CHECK THE VOLUME AT http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=FARM&a=11&b=24&c=2003&d=11&e=24&f=2003&g=d

Comment: It looks like options execution, not a real trade. In any case, volume represents trading on the stock exchange, but insiders may be selling directly to the company, not through an exchange.

Comment: I have checked thomson database now and excluded options also direct interactions. It seems there is still a problem.